# Windows 10 network: We can access to network computers by IP but not by NAME

Tags: windows, networking

We have a network, a Windows 10 workgroup, with fixed IPs and the server is one of the Windows 10 network computers. Some computers can recognize each other in the Network Tab in the file brower and get connected... some others just can't. The only way is to use the IP of the computer or the resource as path. We can ping each computer in the network, we can connect to them by IP but not by the name.

A solution has been found so far: A change in the Hosts file in the path C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
Adding the IPs and the NAME of each network resource in that file, the network works again. But we still don't know why this issue appeared after one of the lastest Windows update.

Any clue to find out the reason of this issue?

Comment: Do you have DNS or WINS service on the network?

Comment: To communicate between computers (on an IP network) by name, each computer must be able to resolve the others’ names to their IP addresses.  What have you done to make this possible? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPv6 active at Ethernet configuration can cause issues in the Workgroup (based on NetBios) after the 1803 Windows 10 Update.

Answer (score 1):

You can ping via hostname,but can't access via it?

Here are something you need to check:

1.Make sure that DNS service has started correctly.

2.Use the command to flush dns

ipconfig /renew

ipconfig /release

inetsh wnsock reset

netsh int ip reset

Netcfg -d

3.Use nsloop , which can give you the IP address assigned to the computer you are looking up according to the DNS table in DNS.

4.If you're running a standard environment, access your local gateway (usually 192.168.0.1, 10.0.0.138 or 192.168.1.1), enter your credentials (usually admin/admin) and check under the configuration that the DNS service is turned on.

5.Check the credentials in control panel>windows credential

6.Check the host file, make sure the IP address has not been pointed to a wrong host name.

Comment: Yes! The Host file edition has been one of the clues.But still, what had made this issue to happen after the updates?

Comment: Another solution, this time provided by Microsoft assistence team is: Uncheck the IPv6 at Ethernet configuration. We have just tried it and we hope is an stable solution. If not, I will add comment here.