# Windows 10, unable to access network samba share by name, able to access by IP address

Tags: windows-10, networking, samba

In the recent times I noticed that after I reboot my Windows 10 Dell laptop, I am unable to access one of my Network shares by name, e.g.: \\my_server. It just returns error that network path is not available. It can still be accessed by IP address \\n.n.n.n, but not by name.
That causes my backup scripts, which I run in bash shell (cygwin) that rely on this network resource by name / linked disk letter to fail.
I could modify my scripts to use IP address, but that isn't really the point or a good practice either.
What if I decide to change the server's IP address to dynamic? My scripts will stop working altogether as well as Windows linkage to the resource by a drive letter.
The temporary remedy is to restart Workstation service in Windows Services manually. (until the next laptop reboot)

My system information
------------------------
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Home
OS Version:                10.0.19041 N/A Build 19041

Note that I have the name of the host defined in my C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file. I can ping that host by name, it is resolved to proper IP address as defined in hosts file. In some other post it was listed as a remedy: https://superuser.com/questions/1340962/windows-10-network-we-can-access-to-network-computers-by-ip-but-not-by-name

It is obviously not my case. It is also not the case of IPv6 enabled on my network adapter. I disabled it and the problem is still there.
I cannot pin this to any recent particular update or software installation as I didn't notice it right away.
It used to work earlier (script runs from Windows Task Scheduler) and I didn't update or change anything about the Samba configuration on the linux server hosting the shared resource. (Using SMB 3.6.25 on server.)
My Windows 10 did receive some feature update recently and I also installed NVidia GeForce Experience.
I don't think NVidia software could have broken it, my bet is on Windows update.
Did anyone experience such problem?
How can this be addressed so I don't have to restart the service manually?

Thanks,

Marek

Answer (score 0):

Has your PC bitlocked or connected to an microsoft account? Also updates didn't change/reset any Windows sharing settings? That may sound stupid but worth a shot.

Recently, after I changed my computer name, it disappeared from network discovery (besides nothing visible changed in settings) but still was accessible via host name.